# Can I say "stuffs" as a plural noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

I know that "stuff" is a collective noun, but other collective nouns like "family" can be pluralized, but "stuffs" doesn't sound quite right to me. However, the spell check on my browser says that "stuffs" is a word.

If "stuffs" is correct, why does it sound wrong to me? If it isn't, then why is it different from other collective nouns?

Comment: It is right. "Stuffs" is the plural of "Stuff". As to why it sounds wrong to you - I have no idea. What do you mean by different?

Comment: It happens in compound like _foodstuffs_; by itself it looks like a singular present tense verb.

Comment: It sounds wrong to me too. I don't know why, maybe because you are already tired after saying 'stuff' and you have to put that extra effort at the end saying 's'.

Comment: Your spell-check doesn't dislike it because it is a valid verb tense:  "John stuffs Twinkies at the factory for a living."

Comment: Some Googling suggests *stuffs* as a noun (by itself) is either in very short usage or just plain wrong. I would avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several cases where collective nouns are pluralized. "Fish" can mean one fish or several fish, but "fishes" usually refer to groupings of different types of fish - so it's a pluralization of the collective, not of the singular.

This could be generalized to this case as well. "Stuff" is a collective noun, but "stuffs" would probably be understood to mean distinctly separated groups of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*foodstuff*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foodstuffs) is the following example sentence:

> // Hyperinflation has put all but the most basic *foodstuffs* and medicines out of reach, leaving those who remain thin, hungry and sick.
> — *Washington Post*, "In Venezuela’s oil capital, life is a struggle. So is death.," 20 Sep. 2019

The pluralization of *stuffs* isn't that much of a leap from the pluralization of *foodstuffs*.

---

There are also other manipulations of English that have allowed for this kind of pluralization.

One has an additional twist, because it pluralizes a noun that shouldn't really be a noun in the first place:

> I have all the **feels**.

Another is a recent slogan from [Arby's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TkoCDWvDoo) [YouTube video]:

> We have the **meats**.

---

Mass nouns are seldom pluralized. However, there are exceptions.

From ["What is the Plural of 'Money?'"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/money-plural-usage-monies) by Merriam-Webster:

> Like common mass nouns such as *water* and *sand*, there are occasions when *money* is inflected with a standard plural, like any count noun. It tends to occur when the reference is to discrete sums of money, obtained from a particular source or allocated to a particular cause.
>
> The spelling in these instance can be moneys or, more commonly, monies:
>
> > Some of the 2009 stimulus *monies* for high-speed rail should end up in the California project and more may be coming.
> > —James McCommons, *Waiting on a Train*, 2009

---

So, the only real reason why *stuffs* could be considered incorrect is simply because it's not normally used. Since it isn't used, it doesn't sound normal. But that doesn't mean that it *can't* be used.

Repetition has made *all the feels* and *we have the meats* sound somewhat normal. Or at least more normal than when they were heard the first time …

Answer (score 0):

Stuffs is a verb. "He stuffs his backpack with clothes." Stuffs is not considered correct English as a noun. It doesn't seem to have utility since it is covered by "stuff".

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide explanation and context. A good answer is complete and explains why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that lack support may be removed.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

"Stuffs" as a noun *is* incorrect. The reason it is different from other collective nouns is because it is also a mass noun. Words like rice, water, smoke, and cement are all mass nouns (or uncountable nouns). You could say "several piles of stuff" to make it plural, but not "several stuffs."

As others have said, "stuffs" is also a verb (present tense singular), so the spellchecker won't count it wrong. Hopefully, a good grammar checker would.

Reference: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stuff

Answer (score -1):

*Stuffs* on it's own is really a verb but if you [type "define stuff" in Google](https://www.google.com/#q=define+stuff) and expand the definition of the noun part you'll find one mention of it as a plural *one's stuffs* it still doesn't sound right though.

Comment: Did you really type just type "on it is own"?  Save the apostrophe for the contraction.

Answer (score -3):

I say the plural 'stuffs' is as much a word as any other. I say stuffs a lot,  which is the plural of stuff, even though stuff already refers to a collection of (plural) things. However, I do say stuffs a lot for fun. Maybe I can make it a legitimate word in the dictionary.

Comment: Your effort is appreciated. Bear in mind that Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers. Anecdotes can be useful, but they are usually not sufficient on their own to show that an answer is right. An answer should include explanation, context, and supporting facts. For example, you could offer peer-reviewed evidence. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: It isn't.  Stuff is already a collective noun meaning more than one thing.